# Equal spacing between div

Tags: html, css

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bo95tw3z/)

Hi, I have three `div` here. I want to give equal spacing on it's left and right side. I want to make it generic.

**PROBLEMS I FACE**

```
1.If i add more `div` element, it requires many CSS changes
2. What if content length increases? It ll decrease it's spacing.
3. I want to make it possible without using width and inline-block.
```

If any solutions possible, please let me know. If we 'MUST' use width or inline-block, suggest that also. Thanks in advance. My css as follows:

```
.wrapper
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #454545;
}

.div1,.div2,.div3
{
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15% 0 10%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you are using, will not work if you change your content or change number of columns. Following are possible solutions as far as I know:

**Option1:**

```
.div {
    width:33.33%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Disadvantages:

1) `inline-block` leaves white space between elements. Comment out spaces between elements i.e.

2) As, column is given `width`, as the columns change, width needs to be changed.

[**Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/bo95tw3z/1/)

**Option2:**

```
.wrapper {
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
.div {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Disadvantages:

1) Doesn't work in IE7.

[**Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/bo95tw3z/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your solution Hiral. I ll try this and let you know.

Comment: Hiral, one more doubt. Does second solution suits for div of different width content?

Comment: @user3801433 yes just remove `table-layout:fixed;` from `.wrapper`.